# Loading Image From Url gets Rotated Android

Tags: android

I'm **trying to load image from url** and it **gets rotated**

I've **searched for ExifOrientation** for image coming from url but **got failed**.

my **image url** is **http://goo.gl/Y52pTo**

this image taken from iPhone camera and it gets rotated in android device

I've **tried this solution** but **not working** for URLs i think,

**https://gist.github.com/9re/1990019**

So, **how can i represent image in original orientation?**

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `it gets rotated in android device`. No. Not here in browser. And not in Gallery app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my code that i've used to solve it,

First of all download image.

```
new GetFileTask(new FileDownloadListener() {

                @Override
                public void onFileDownload(String path) {


                }
            }).execute(image_url, "image_name");

public interface FileDownloadListener{
    public void onFileDownload(String path);

}


public class GetFileTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
private FileDownloadListener downloadListner;

public GetFileTask(FileDownloadListener downloadListner) {
    this.downloadListner = downloadListner;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String path) {
    super.onPostExecute(path);
    // Log.e("FILE_DOWNLOAD", "DOWNLOAD end: " +
    // System.currentTimeMillis());
    File f = new File(path);
    if (f.exists()) {
        downloadListner.onFileDownload(path);
    }
}

/*
 * param 0 : url param 1 : file name without path
 */
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        // Log.e("FILE_DOWNLOAD",
        // "DOWNLOAD Start: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        File dir = new File(General.TempImagePath);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs(); // create complete path require to create this
                            // directory
        }

        URL ulrn = new URL(params[0]);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) ulrn.openConnection();
        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
        // Log.e("FILE_DOWNLOAD",
        // "DOWNLOAD InputStream: " + System.currentTimeMillis());

        String fileName = (params[1] == null) ? String.valueOf(System
                .currentTimeMillis()) : params[1];

        try {
            OutputStream fOut = null;
            File file = new File(General.TempImagePath, fileName);
            if (file.exists()) {
                file.delete();
            }

            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                fOut.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            // Log.e("FILE_DOWNLOAD",
            // "DOWNLOAD file-read: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
            is.close();

            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();

            return file.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

then using its path get rotated bitmap like this,

```
public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(String src, Bitmap bitmap) {
    try {
        int orientation = getExifOrientation(src);

        if (orientation == 1) {
            return bitmap;
        }

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        switch (orientation) {
        case 2:
            matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
            break;
        case 3:
            matrix.setRotate(180);
            break;
        case 4:
            matrix.setRotate(180);
            matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
            break;
        case 5:
            matrix.setRotate(90);
            matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
            break;
        case 6:
            matrix.setRotate(90);
            break;
        case 7:
            matrix.setRotate(-90);
            matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
            break;
        case 8:
            matrix.setRotate(-90);
            break;
        default:
            return bitmap;
        }

        try {
            Bitmap oriented = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                    bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            bitmap.recycle();
            return oriented;
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return bitmap;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bitmap;
}

private static int getExifOrientation(String src) throws IOException {
    int orientation = 1;

    try {
        /**
         * if your are targeting only api level >= 5 ExifInterface exif =
         * new ExifInterface(src); orientation =
         * exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
         */
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 5) {
            Class<?> exifClass = Class
                    .forName("android.media.ExifInterface");
            Constructor<?> exifConstructor = exifClass
                    .getConstructor(new Class[] { String.class });
            Object exifInstance = exifConstructor
                    .newInstance(new Object[] { src });
            Method getAttributeInt = exifClass.getMethod("getAttributeInt",
                    new Class[] { String.class, int.class });
            Field tagOrientationField = exifClass
                    .getField("TAG_ORIENTATION");
            String tagOrientation = (String) tagOrientationField.get(null);
            orientation = (Integer) getAttributeInt.invoke(exifInstance,
                    new Object[] { tagOrientation, 1 });
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return orientation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if its happening every single time then you can rotate the image after downloading it....

Comment: Thanks... for giving me idea.

Comment: Its not happening every single time. it happens for images those i are taken from iPhone Camera and uploaded to server.